# Rails 7.0 `Object.group` delivers Object doesn't support #inspect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7

I've got orders which can be made from different suppliers. I want to group the total amount of money paid by the said supplier.

My `SupplierOrder.rb`:

```rb
class SupplierOrder < ApplicationRecord
  include Order

  belongs_to :product
  has_many :payments, as: :payable, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :payments, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Now, a simple `SupplierOrder.group(:supplier)` in the console delivers me:

```
SupplierOrder.group(:supplier)
  SupplierOrder Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "supplier_orders".* FROM "supplier_orders" GROUP BY "supplier_orders"."supplier"
(Object doesn't support #inspect)
 =>
```

If it's helpful, here my `schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "supplier_orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.float "paid"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.float "price"
    t.string "supplier"
    t.string "order_number"
    t.integer "amount"
    t.bigint "product_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_supplier_orders_on_product_id"
  end
```

Here is my `order.rb Concern` (`models/concerns/order.rb'):

```rb
module Order
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def full_title
    self.product.full_title
  end
end
```

Right now I'm getting `supplier`-Value from a global variable, defined in `helpers/application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  SIZES = %w(1:1 1:2 1:3 1:4 1:5 1:6 1:7 1:8)
  VERSIONS = %w(regular deluxe exclusive)
  COLORS = %w(black blue white)
  SUPPLIERS = %w(A B C D)
end
```

I don't override any initializers like in linked topics or do anything extraordinary. All (at least for now) other methods do work in the console, but just this one is not.

Comment: Could you share the content of the `Order` module please ?

Comment: Sure, added it in my edit

Comment: Do you have a `Supplier` class/module defined somewhere ?

Comment: No, the `supplier` inside a `SupplierOrder` is just a text value. Coming from a constant, defined in `helper/application_helper.rb`

Comment: Yep, I was just thinking that it could lead to a clash between the string field and a potential `Supplier` model. I guess that `puts SupplierOrder.first` and `SupplierOrder.first.supplier` are working well, right ?

Comment: Yes, those 2 work and a lot of other methods I'm using work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Add `gem 'pry-rails'` in your development group in Gemfile and run `bundle install` and execute the command again in rails console.

Comment: That is my console output now:
`pry(main)> SupplierOrder.group(:supplier)
  SupplierOrder Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "supplier_orders".* FROM "supplier_orders" GROUP BY "supplier_orders"."supplier"
=> #<SupplierOrder::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x4038>`

Comment: Can you explicitly select supplier_orders.supplier and try again
Something like `SupplierOrder.select("supplier_orders.supplier").group(:supplier)`

Comment: Yes, that works:
`pry(main)> SupplierOrder.select("supplier_orders.supplier").group(:supplier)
  SupplierOrder Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "supplier_orders"."supplier" FROM "supplier_orders" GROUP BY "supplier_orders"."supplier"
=> [#<SupplierOrder:0x00007f8371486718 id: nil, supplier: "Supplier A">, #<SupplierOrder:0x00007f83713aa678 id: nil, supplier: "Supplier B">]`.

I have tried something similar with an array -> `SupplierOrder.all.to_a.group_by(&:supplier)` and it works as well. Would prefer the native `group` implementation thou

Comment: Can you please tell in what format do you want the data?
I can help you with the query

Comment: Hash I guess: `{"Supplier A" => { [payment_1], [payment_2] }, "Supplier B" => { [payment_3], [payment_4] } }` Something like that

Comment: I'm not sure about the schema thar you are using but you should be using `array_agg` to select columns when you are using `group by` clause.

Something like `SupplierOrder.select("supplier_orders.supplier, array_agg(customers.id) as customers_ids").group(:supplier).first.atributes `

Comment: @maya_nk99 this doesn't seem to be an actual answer. For debugging aid, you can use comments or start a chat.